# Next Auth Js with subdomain / 2 different login page

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm currently building a multi-tenant application.

So the idea is that I have users who will sign up for the application, which will allow them to manage their clients. They have the option to manage a small blog, so they will have a subdomain like this: user1.mywebsite.com... The issue I'm facing is that for users, they need to log in to this URL app.mywebsite.com through NextAuth with providers like Google or GitHub... then they are redirected to their respective Dashboard where they can manage their mini blog, add clients, etc.

What I would like to do now is, through the subdomain of my user, so user1.mywebsite.com, be able to add a different login page, so my user's clients will need to log in on my user's subdomain, and my users need to log in on app.website.com.

I would like to proceed in this way to offer personalized management for my users, which would allow them to strengthen their branding...

Is this technically possible with NextAuth? I've tried to find solutions on the internet, but it's never really what I want to do

Thank you

I looked for examples of this situation on internet but found nothing like i would like to do.